# XML file not loading while trying in UFT (VB script)

Tags: xml, vbscript, hp-uft

I have a requirement to read XML file from UFT and extract few values.
Unfortunately by below code is not working. I see that XML file itself is not loading, I have tried with multiple files and still no success. Please help me with any suggestions.

Below is my code to open Response.xml file

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async= False
path = "C:\Users\axxxx\Desktop\Response.xml" 
If xmlDoc.LoadXml(path) then
msgbox " file loaded "
else
msgbox "file not loaded"
End If
```

Above code displays file not loaded.
Am using UFT 14.50 and Windows 10

I have tried many xml files and nothing is getting loaded. 
Is it something to do with MSXML, I have checked that MSXML6.dll (Highest version) is available in system 32 folder.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I found the solution.
New code is below. Just changed XMLDoc.LoadXML to XMLDoc.Load and it worked

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async= False
path = "C:\Users\axxxx\Desktop\Response.xml" 
If xmlDoc.Load(path) then
msgbox " file loaded "
else
msgbox "file not loaded"
End If
```

Comment: I suggest you use the `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0` namespace instead of `Microsoft.XMLDOM` as its the latest one